# nginx: worker process: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000000ee8c00

Tags: nginx

1. pstack

   ```
   pstack 27339
   #0  0x00000037c600cd2b in pthread_once () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
   #1  0x00000037c5cfe954 in backtrace () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #2  0x00000037c5c7054b in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #3  0x00000037c5c75e66 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #4  0x00000037c5c79904 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #5  0x00000037c5c7a6b1 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #6  0x00000037c580cc5d in _dl_map_object_deps () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
   #7  0x00000037c5812b62 in dl_open_worker () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
   #8  0x00000037c580e266 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
   #9  0x00000037c58125aa in _dl_open () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
   #10 0x00000037c5d26b20 in do_dlopen () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #11 0x00000037c580e266 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
   #12 0x00000037c5d26c77 in __libc_dlopen_mode () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #13 0x00000037c5cfe825 in init () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #14 0x00000037c600cd33 in pthread_once () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
   #15 0x00000037c5cfe954 in backtrace () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #16 0x00000037c5c7054b in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #17 0x00000037c5c75e66 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #18 0x00000037c5c79904 in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #19 0x00000037c5c7a6b1 in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
   #20 0x0000000000457e1a in ngx_alloc ()
   #21 0x0000000000443d92 in ngx_palloc_large ()
   #22 0x0000000000443e95 in ngx_palloc ()
   #23 0x00000000004456ec in ngx_create_temp_buf ()
   #24 0x000000000049f79b in ajp_msg_create_buffer ()
   #25 0x00000000004a22de in ngx_http_ajp_create_request ()
   #26 0x0000000000479593 in ngx_http_upstream_init_request ()
   #27 0x0000000000479955 in ngx_http_upstream_init ()
   #28 0x00000000004712f8 in ngx_http_read_client_request_body ()
   #29 0x00000000004a1a6f in ngx_http_ajp_handler ()
   #30 0x000000000046725d in ngx_http_core_content_phase ()
   #31 0x0000000000462a23 in ngx_http_core_run_phases ()
   #32 0x00000000004a6ac4 in npc_sendRequest ()
   #33 0x000000000045cc9f in ngx_epoll_process_events ()
   #34 0x0000000000455c83 in ngx_process_events_and_timers ()
   #35 0x000000000045b684 in ngx_worker_process_cycle ()
   #36 0x0000000000459e55 in ngx_spawn_process ()
   #37 0x000000000045bfe9 in ngx_master_process_cycle ()
   #38 0x000000000044318d in main ()
   ```
2. error log

   ```
   *** glibc detected *** nginx: worker process: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000000ee8c00 ***
   *** glibc detected *** nginx: worker process: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000000ee8c00 ***
   ```
3. var /proc/pid/stack

   ```
   [<ffffffff810a9a49>] futex_wait_queue_me+0xb9/0xf0
   [<ffffffff810aab58>] futex_wait+0x1f8/0x380
   [<ffffffff810ac2c1>] do_futex+0x121/0xb60
   [<ffffffff810acd7b>] sys_futex+0x7b/0x170
   [<ffffffff8100b072>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
   [<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
   ```

When I got the error, nginx process hanged.
because of the malloc error process, all proceses hang Sometimes.

In error log, there are no backtrace. 
So, I guess there is a dead lock between malloc and backtrace(or printerr).

I used 'accept_mutex off' option, and it just reduced the error. (It's not a perfect solution)

I'm using nginx-0.8.54.